# Separating embedded/nested data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that has embedded within it, another data frame

```
class(data)
[1] "dfidx_mlogit" "dfidx"        "data.frame"   "mlogit.data"
```

I am trying to seperate the two data frames apart. One that includes the pertinent data on health and education and the other which contains information about the persons id, called 'idx'.

How do I completely separate the two data frames?

Here is the following data

```
data <- structure(list(EDUC = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), HEALTH = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), idx = structure(list(chid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), unique_id = c(3000175513, 
3000175513, 3000175513, 3000175513), alt = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Bicycle", 
"Car", "Metro", "Walking"), class = "factor")), ids = c(1, 1, 
2), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("idx", "data.frame"))), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = c("dfidx_mlogit", "dfidx", "data.frame", "mlogit.data"
), idx = structure(list(chid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), unique_id = c(3000175513, 
3000175513, 3000175513, 3000175513), alt = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Bicycle", 
"Car", "Metro", "Walking"), class = "factor")), ids = c(1, 1, 
2), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("idx", "data.frame")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to separate the datasets, it is the 'id' column that have a nested 'data.frame'.  We can `pull` that column to create a new object

```
library(dplyr)
data2 <- data %>% 
              pull(idx) 
data1 <- data %>% 
             as_tibble %>% 
             select(-idx)
attr(data1, "idx") <- NULL
```

-checking the structure

```
str(data1)
#tibble [4 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# $ EDUC  : int [1:4] 4 4 4 4
# $ HEALTH: int [1:4] 3 3 3 3
str(data2)
#Classes ‘idx’ and 'data.frame':    4 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ chid     : int  1 1 1 1
# $ unique_id: num  3e+09 3e+09 3e+09 3e+09
# $ alt      : Factor w/ 4 levels "Bicycle","Car",..: 1 2 3 4
# - attr(*, "ids")= num [1:3] 1 1 2
```

---

Or doing this in `base R`

```
data2 <- data$idx
class(data2) <- 'data.frame'
data1 <- data[1:2]
```

-checking the structure

```
str(data1)
#Classes ‘dfidx_mlogit’, ‘dfidx’, ‘mlogit.data’ and 'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ EDUC  : int  4 4 4 4
# $ HEALTH: int  3 3 3 3



str(data2)
#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ chid     : int  1 1 1 1
# $ unique_id: num  3e+09 3e+09 3e+09 3e+09
# $ alt      : Factor w/ 4 levels "Bicycle","Car",..: 1 2 3 4
# - attr(*, "ids")= num [1:3] 1 1 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is use of the dplyr package the only way of separating these two data frames? Is there no easier way?

Comment: Thank you for your help Akrun. The base command did not work, it still includes the 'idx' dataframe. Hard to remove.

Comment: @jessica I would reset the `class` attribute. updated.  These are attributes created based on the function you applied.  We can modify/replace/insert attrributes as needed with assignment

Answer (score 1):

A general solution would be to separate data based on their `class`.

```
data1 <- Filter(function(x) all(class(x) != "data.frame"), data)
data2 <- data$idx
#Or maybe we can generalise this as well
#data2 <- Filter(function(x) any(class(x) == "data.frame"), data)
str(data1)

#Classes ‘dfidx_mlogit’, ‘dfidx’, ‘mlogit.data’ and 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ EDUC  : int  4 4 4 4
# $ HEALTH: int  3 3 3 3

str(data2)
#Classes ‘idx’ and 'data.frame':    4 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ chid     : int  1 1 1 1
# $ unique_id: num  3e+09 3e+09 3e+09 3e+09
# $ alt      : Factor w/ 4 levels "Bicycle","Car",..: 1 2 3 4
# - attr(*, "ids")= num [1:3] 1 1 2
```